# unordered_map find only items after the previously found item

Tags: c++, c++14, unordered-map

I have a unordered_map, that contains an enum and a string as a second. The first value may appear many times in different orders. Here's an example:

```
enum SomeType
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
};

static std::unordered_map<SomeType, std::string> value_map =
{
    { TYPE2, "Value that shouldn't be found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found first" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that also never gets found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found second" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that gets found last" },
};
```

I'd like to iterate through the map as follows: For example first I'd like to find the pair for `TYPE1`, which would net me the first `TYPE1` value. After that searching for a `TYPE1` value again wouldn't net me the first one, but rather the next one that can be found after it. Searching for a `TYPE2` value after that would only net the last value.
Basically I want to find only the next matching value, but none ever preceding the last found value.

I tried multiple times to implement something that does this, but I'm not quite sure how to implement such an algorithm.
How would one implement such an algorithm?

Full code sample that tries to demonstrate what I want: https://godbolt.org/g/CgNZnj

Comment: FYI, the key for a map has to be unique.  You cannot have multiple elements with the same key.

Comment: Note the component name, **Unordered** map. The order of insertion has nothing to do with the order of traversal.

Comment: You need a vector/deque/list/forward_list/array of pairs. All the associative containers, ordered or unordered, either require unique keys, or group equivalent keys together.

Comment: _"I have a unordered_map, that contains an enum and a string as a second. The first value may appear many times in different orders."_ No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

enum SomeType
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3,
};

using value_map = std::vector<std::pair<SomeType, std::string>>;

class ValueMap
{
public:
    ValueMap(value_map& map) : map(map), index(0) {}

    value_map& map;

    std::string find_next(SomeType type)
    {
        while ((index != map.size()) && (map[index].first != type))
        {
            ++index;
        }

        if (index != map.size())
        {
            std::string result = map[index].second;
            ++index;
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return "-";
        }
    }

private:
    unsigned index;
};

static value_map some_value_map =
{
    { TYPE2, "Value that shouldn't be found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found first" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that also never gets found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found second" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that gets found last" },
};

static ValueMap value_mapper(some_value_map);

int main()
{
    std::cout << value_mapper.find_next(TYPE1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << value_mapper.find_next(TYPE1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << value_mapper.find_next(TYPE2) << std::endl;

    std::string some_string = value_mapper.find_next(TYPE1);

    if (some_string == "-")
    {
        std::cout << "Didn't find a match" << std::endl;
    }

    value_mapper.map.push_back({ TYPE3, "Value that gets after the last as new" });
    std::cout << value_mapper.find_next(TYPE3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
Value that gets found first
Value that gets found second
Value that gets found last
Didn't find a match
Value that gets after the last as new
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You might want a std::unordered_multimap (multimap) and use equal_range:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

enum SomeType
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
};

static std::unordered_multimap<unsigned, std::string> value_map =
{
    { TYPE2, "Value that shouldn't be found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found first" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that also never gets found" },
    { TYPE1, "Value that gets found second" },
    { TYPE2, "Value that gets found last" },
};

int main() {
    auto range = value_map.equal_range(TYPE1);
    for( auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i )
        std::cout << i->second << '\n';
}
```

However:

- The result range is not sorted (stays unordered).
- If you want to keep the relative order of equal keys used in initialization, replace `unordered_multimap` by `multimap`.
- If you want to keep the initialization order entirely, use a sequence container (std::vector) of key/value pairs. The associative containers set, map (and their undorderd and/or multi variants) do not preserve the order.

Conclusion:

Realizing your search requirements in an algorithm operating on an associative container is impossible.

Comment: Is `value_type` needed here?

Comment: @DieterLücking In you main, if you delete `using value_type` line and instead of  `std::for_each` statement write `for( auto i = range.first; i != range.second; ++i ) std::cout << i->second << '\n';`, will output will be equivalent to what you have now?

Comment: It's possible to advance the iterator to the desired position using std::advance (ie. the last used value) and then search using a for each loop in the desired range (last used iterator pos, end of the map) for the desired value. This would accomplish what I aimed to achieve. Thank you for the leads.